# Convert CSS3 animation into JQuery for use in IE8 and above

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I posted a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926065/how-do-i-hide-my-custom-css-overflow-in-ie8) yesterday and after 5 or more hours of fighting with IE8 just to  hide the overlay text before the transition happened, I have decided that the only way to fix the issue is to convert it to JQuery. I have a css animation that I need to change over to jquery or javascript because IE8 displays the overlay text before the `hover` occurs. Because the CSS is quite lengthy I made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atnD8/2/). The css transitions occur on lines 25 and 44.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you tried converting it? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: the question is How do I convert it. I have not tried because I do not know where to start. The only thing I have tried is getting the overlay text to hide before the transition in IE8.

Comment: @Blender calm down dude...hes done plenty of work that is some brilliant CSS and I have seen several questions posted on here of people asking for help converting CSS to jquery. Look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449887/how-to-convert-css3-transition-easing-to-jquery-easing-function

Comment: @Skullomania have you tried the suggestion posted to you yesterday? what happens?

Comment: All it does is underlines the overlay text in red for some reason. Like I mentioned earlier I played around with it for 5 or so hours before passing out and I am no expert on JQuery. However I did see others posting questions for others to help convert their CSS. I didn't mean to offend, or try to pass off my work as it was mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, you can tinker with the numbers if you want. I don't have IE so I can't test it but it should be good:

```
$(".cascade-t1").hover(function(){
    $(".cascade-corner").fadeOut();
    $(".overlay-t1").animate({"left": "-300px"}, 300, function(){
        $(".cascade-overlay-content").fadeIn(200);    
    });


}, function(){

   $(".cascade-corner").fadeIn();
   $(".cascade-overlay-content").fadeOut(200, function(){
       $(".overlay-t1").animate({"left": "130px"}, 300);    
    });

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9nxFc/)